# iOS : refreshing already loaded tableView

Tags: ios

Is there a 'shorter' way to write it ? seems to be a long way to get the playersViewController instance ...

```
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    PlayersViewController *playersViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [playersViewController.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I am refreshing the an already loaded tableView

```
#pragma mark - RatePlayerViewControllerDelegate
- (void)ratePlayerViewController: (RatePlayerViewController *)controller didPickRatingForPlayer:(Player *)player
{
    if (player.rating != self.requiredRating)
    {
    // do stuff.. in self.tableView
    // refresh players tableView
```

Comment: Some context would be nice.

Comment: MVC: first you have to change the model (data) and then update UI (view) accordingly

Comment: this is performed in another class , rankingviewcontroller in which the user rates a player... once done, the players view needs to be updated with the new ranking
so there are 4 lines to get the playersviewcontroller tableview then last line is reloading the players data ( with the new ranking)

my concern is how to shorten ( if possible) these 4 lines... but it may not be possible....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use notification

**PlayersViewController.m**

add this line in your init method :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadPlayers:) name:@"reloadPlayersNotification" object:nil];
```

and implement the method

```
- (void)reloadPlayers:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Remember to remove your observer when your tableView must not receive reloadData call (for example if the tableView is not visible)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name@"reloadPlayersNotification" object:nil]
```

and now if you want to reload this tableView from another class :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"reloadPlayersNotification"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload your `UITableView` simply use `[self.tableView reloadData]`

EDIT: One thing to remember as well, you should always update views on the main thread. Im not sure what you're doing exactly, but it never hurts to be safe rather than sorry. The following would reload your tableView on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: He wants to reload the tableview from a different class, so `self.tableview` won't work.  Also, there is no indication that multithreading comes into play for the OP's question.

Comment: @AaronBrager self.tableView was not meant to be literal I assumed he could extrapolate the meaning and provide his own tableView. He would simply change it to `playersViewController.tableView`. Moreover, neither I nor you know whats going on in the rest of his app or why hes reloading the table. Its better to be safe rather than sorry and always update on the main thread.

Comment: you're right Aaaron, I do it from a different class and there is no multithreading... 
I update on the main thread ... 5th line is :
    [playersViewController.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
this is working fine...
I am concern only by all the previous lines needed to get the playersViewController... from another class...